# Rolling-window matrix with different intervals between columns

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, sliding-window

I have a vector of data for 21 years with daily data and want to create a rolling window of 365 days such as the next period stars one month (30 days) after the previous one.  In the question, `n_interval` defines the difference between the first data point of the next window and the last observation of the previous series.

Let's assume my daily data start from Jan. 1 2000, then the first column would be Jan. 1, 2000 -Jan.1, 2001 and the second column starts from Feb. 1, 2000. and ends on Feb. 1, 2001. and ... the last column will cover Jan. 1, 2017 to Jan. 1, 2018.  for example if:

```
vec = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
```

for a given variable `n_interval = 3`, `with window_size=5`, the output matrix should look like:

```
mat = [[1 4 7  10  13],
       [2 5 8  11  14],
       [3 6 9  12  15],
       [4 7 10 13  16],
       [5 8 11 14  17]]
```

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify the expected behavior of the n_interval value? Not sure I understand the question! Maybe a little more source code would help

Comment: Not all rows in your example output have the same number of elements (the last has 4, the rest 5), and as such you cannot save this in a matrix. What do you want to do? Save it in a different format or pad it with NaN?

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger I edited the question, though the last column's length was different on purpose, that is not a big deal.

Comment: How is the number of columns of `mat` determined?

Comment: @LuisMendo It will depend on the n_interval. In my case every year is 365 days and n_intervals is 30, then the number of columns will be fixed accordingly.

Comment: @PeterBarrettBryan, sorry for ambiguity, I edited the question.

Comment: I don't understand how the example corresponds to the original question. To recreate the example you can use the following horrible one liner `mat = vec(mod(bsxfun(@plus, 0:(k-1), (1:n:(numel(vec)-n+1))')-1,numel(vec))+1)` where `n=3` and `k=5` is the number of columns.

Comment: Let me be more specific. In your example, how do we know if you want `[1 2 3 4 5; 4 5 6 7 8; 7 8 9 10 11; 10 11 12 13 14]` or `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11; 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14]`?

Comment: @Luis Mendo, I got your point. Sorry for the confusing question, I updated it.

Comment: Then jodag's comment above with a final transpose does the job. It can perhaps be simplified to `vec(bsxfun(@plus, 0:(k-1), (1:n:(numel(vec)-n+1))')).'`

Comment: @Luis Mend: Jodag's code worked, but when I run yours with real data I get an error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: I used a bit of [voodoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming) to come up with the `numel(vec)-n+1` bound. Turns out it only worked because of the specific value of `n` and `k`. I posted a more principled approach in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example vector

```
vec = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17];
```

we can create an indexing scheme by as follows:

First, we need to determine how many rows there will be in the `mat`. Assuming we want every element of `vec` to be expressed in `mat` at least once then we need to make sure that last index in the last row is greater than or equal to the size of `vec`. It's fairly easy to see that the index of the last column in `mat` is described by

```
last_index = n_interval*(n_rows-1) + n_columns
```

We want to ensure that `last_index >= numel(vec)`. Substituting in the above expression into the inequality and solving for `n_rows` gives

```
n_rows >= (numel(vec) - n_columns)/n_interval + 1
```

We assign `n_rows` to be the `ceil` of this bound so that it is the smallest integer which satisfies the inequality. Now that we know the number of rows we generate the list of starting indices for each row

```
start_index = 1:n_interval:(n_interval*(n_rows-1)+1);
```

In the index matrix we want each column to be 1 plus the previous column. In other words we want to offset the column according to the array `index_offset = 0:(n_interval-1)`.

Using `bsxfun` we generate the index matrix by computing the sums of all pairs between the `start_index` and `index_offset` arrays

```
index = bsxfun(@plus, index_offset, start_index');
```

The final thing we need to worry about is going out of bounds. To handle this we apply the `mod` function to wrap the out of bounds indicies:

```
index_wrapped = mod(index-1, numel(vec))+1;
```

Then we simply sample the vector according to `index_wrapped`

```
mat = vec(index_wrapped);
```

---

The complete code is

```
n_interval = 3;
n_columns = 5;
vec = 1:17;

n_rows = ceil((numel(vec)-n_columns)/n_interval + 1);
start_index = 1:n_interval:(n_interval*(n_rows-1)+1);
index_offset = 0:(n_columns-1);
index = bsxfun(@plus, index_offset, start_index');
index_wrapped = mod(index-1, numel(vec))+1;
mat = vec(index_wrapped);
```

Comment: It's a very flexible solution,